# Could the Aurora D8 have Ramjets instead of traditional jet engines?

Tags: ramjet, double-bubble-d8

By the  design of the [Aurora D8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora_D8), the engines would receive the boundary layer of air atop the fuselage, however, because jets have what I am calling "moving parts", and the pressure differences would cause problems for the turbines. Could we eliminate this factor with ramjet engines?

Comment: It would cause even more problems for rams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the turbines with ramjets won't work.

If the airplane had ramjet(s), it would still need enough thrust from non-ramjet engines to reach about Mach 0.5, because ramjets can't accelerate from a standstill, and they make hardly any thrust below that speed.  See the [Nord Griffon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nord_1500_Griffon), for example.

Answer (score 2):

The Aurora D8 doesn't have traditional jet engines at all. The design incorporates a very large bypass fan which due to its size is not mechanically linked to the engine core. It's more like a turbo-prop engine, but driving a ducted fan instead of a propeller. The fan is specifically designed to cope with the flow disturbance in the boundary layer. Indeed, according to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora_D8)

> Clustering the engines together atop the wide tail of a flattened fuselage enables them to reenergize the slow-moving boundary layer over the fuselage

Take a look at that article. It might answer a few more of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rauligio and welcome to ASE.

As an answer to your question: no. As the Aurora D8 is designed to fly at subsonic speeds, and ramjets [work most efficiently at supersonic speeds around mach 3](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramjet), they simply would not be feasible on Aurora D8.